# With space when I add a picture

Tags: css

When I add a picture, I have a white space which appears?
On this message below a member explains that it is imperative to use  `vertical-align: bottom;` into my image class.

[Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

So, I have tried, but I always have the same problem, in fact?!...

The picture doesn't appear correctly into the frame.

```
.img-wrapper{
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 72%;
    margin: auto;/*
    background-color: red;*/
    text-align: center;
   
}

.item-col{
    background-color:rgba(139,0,0,0.3);
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 22%;
    margin: 0 10px;
  
}


.img-wrapper{
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item-col">
   <img class="img-wrapper"src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/18/3chm.jpg"alt="image">
   </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: remove the margin from `.img-wrapper`?

Comment: @doğukan: ah yess, thank you